# Not able to connect with hls plugin in red5

Tags: java, red5, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am using recently introduced hls plugin for red5.

When I am trying to connect with hlsapp, red5 giving me this error :

Exception in thread "Launcher:/hlsapp" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load webapplication context class
    at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:611)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'segmenter.service' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:590)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.setTurboCharged(ToolFactory.java:409)
    at org.red5.service.httpstream.SegmenterService.afterPropertiesSet(SegmenterService.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)

[WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-9] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection – Closing RTMPMinaConnection from 192.168.1.114:34215 to 192.168.1.114 (in: 3443 out: 3221), with id -1 due to long handshake

Also I do not understand how to connect with the HLS plugin right now I am doing it by passing “rtmp://192.168.1.114/hlsapp/user_id/video_name” , same is working for oflaDemo “rtmp://192.168.1.114/oflaDemo/user_id/video_name”.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am using jdk7, xuggler, red5 1.0.2

Any help will be really appreciable

Answer (score 1):

That error would seem to indicate that the Xuggler libraries cannot be located. Ensure that you have the xuggler jars in the red5/lib directory.